# ways of using ninject properly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, ninject

One of the definition of ninject in internet is;

> "Somewhere in the middle of your application, you're creating a class
>   inside another class. That means you're creating a dependency.
>   Dependency Injection is about passing in those dependencies, usually
>   through the constructor, instead of embedding them."

what i want to learn is, where ever we see a creation of a class inside another class should we use ninject or just we should use in some part of program that we want/need to apply loosely coupling for design purposes because maybe we would like to use different approaches in the future?

Sorry if this is a silly question.

Comment: If you want to learn Dependency Injection, you should definitely read [Dependency Injection in .NET](https://www.manning.com/books/dependency-injection-in-dot-net).

Comment: @Steven ok thanks. I will.

Comment: this: "just we should use in some part of program that we want/need to apply loosely coupling for design purposes because maybe we would like to use different approaches in the future"

Answer (score 0):

It's a perfectly valid question, and there are no absolute right or wrong answers. Ninject and other IoC frameworks are designed to de-couple dependencies.

So the moment you do this:

```
public class MyClass1
{
    public MyClass1()
    {
        MyClass2 mc2 = new MyClass2();
    }
}
```

You can categorically say that MyClass1 has a dependency in MyClass2.

For me, my rule is this: do I need to unit test MyClass1, or is it likely I'll need to unit test MyClass1?

If I don't need to unit test it, then I don't find much value in decoupling the two classes.

However, if I do need to unit test MyClass1, then injecting in MyClass2 gives you much better control over your unit tests (and allows you to test MyClass1 in isolation).

You do need to evaluate each case separately though. In the above example, if I need to unit test MyClass1, and MyClass2 is just a basic string formatting class, then I probably wouldn't decouple it. However, if MyClass2 was an email sending class then I would de-couple it. I don't want my unit tests actually sending emails, so I would feed in a fake for my tests instead.

So I don't believe there are any solid rules, but hopefully the above gives you a better idea of when you might decouple, and when you might not decouple.